# Find the next number in the weird sequence

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

The following sequence has been made using a specific pattern and the last number is kept secret. We have to find that number along with the pattern followed to make the sequence.

> 3, 11, 32, 71, 136, x

What is x? I was given this problem by a friend and I have been thinking about it for quite a while now but can't think of any possible pattern.

Comment: This puzzle is [not very interesting](http://oeis.org/A089620)...

Comment: *Bass* is correct that this is a pointless puzzle due to over-fitting. But it is worth for you to see why by looking at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2358577/21820).

Answer (score -3):

> 229 n^3 added to the nth prime

Comment: This is overfitting: you were given 5 data points, and you used 4 degrees of freedom (a 3rd degree polynomial plus another arbitrary sequence). You can fit _any_ five numbers with that method. Admittedly, the puzzle is underspecified, but typing numbers into OEIS and posting whatever comes up (without mentioning that the answer is from oeis) isn't how this site is supposed to work, either.

Comment: this doesn`t make any sense

Comment: The sense is that if you give me any five numbers, I can construct the next number using a logic that consists of a third degree polynomial and another number sequence. This is a problem with the question, and posted under the answer only because the answer is required to understand the comment. The problem with the answer (mentioned in the comment above) is the most likely reason for the downvotes.